# How to test a grails Criteria query?

Tags: testing, grails, criteria

first post here and hopefully relevant to many people.

I'm working on writing integration tests for a domain and on that domain I have a query using the `withCriteria()` method. I've searched all over the net and found many that give you detailed instructions on how to go about mocking a criteria query, but none on how to exactly test it.

I've tried mocking the domain using the `mockDomain(domain,list)` function, and setting up a domain for the test to use in the `setUp()` then calling the criteria and I get nothing.
I did a similar `findBy` here and got the results, but not exactly the ones I was looking for. I'm pretty sure it's not just my query, but the criteria, I've read in a few places criteria does not work in service testing. The query thus far has worked for me in the app, but I want to have some tests that I can refer to later in case my code base changes.

I've actually done as many have suggested and pulled out the code for the query and made it a static method in my domain so that I can mock it for the tests that use it, but now I'm stuck with how to actually test this part. Do I need to run the app and just do functional testing from that standpoint, or is there some way I could do this in the grails unit/integration testing. I'll post my query below.

```
static Attribute getDefinitionsUsingCriteria(List categoryNames, List types){
        def definitions = Definition.withCriteria() {
            and {
                'in'('type', types)
                if (categoryNames) {
                    categories {
                        'in'('name', categoryNames)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return definitions
    }
```

Definitions has a string property type, and has a property categories of type `Set` that each element in this set has a `String` name property.

I'm still pretty new to grails and have been reading many reference books, and I'm surprised this is missing in all of the books I've read thus far. I hope this is something that is just a mistake on my part, and easily testable. I appreciate any help, and thanks for reading this long post.

JR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way: move the test from `test/unit` to `test/integration` folder. Criteria won't work in unit test (there's no Hibernate there), but will in integration. Never use `mockDomain()` in integration tests.

Note: don't make the method static - it only complicates testing.

Second way: In unit tests - use `mockDomain()`. Just rely on the fact that the logic is pretty straightforward, and unit-test everything except the method. Override it in `setUp()` like:

```
Definition.metaClass.getDefinitionsUsingCriteria = { List categoryNames, List types ->
    delegate.findAll{ (it.type in types) && 
        (it.categories.find { c -> c in categoryNames }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree - don't unit test persistence, you're just testing the mocking framework. Test persistence using integration tests with a database, either the default in-memory database or a 'real' one.

Comment: Hey Victor, I do have it in the test/integration folder. I originally had the query in a service file, but wasn't getting the list results I expected from the tests,.. They all came back as empty lists. I shall however try again and remove the static. I did however finish all the testing and I guess for the moment I'll go with the second way. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Then, absolutely, the query must work. Do you have any data in the database at that point? What if you try calling `Definition.list()` or the criteria code itself in `grails console`?

Comment: I assume I have the data correctly in the database. I'm using the mockDomain() method to do so. As in, mockDomain(Definition,[new Defintion(ownerType:"type1")]) for a simple one and that seems to work for the Definition.list().

For my testing, when I do Definition.list() I get back the whole mockedDomain I made for that method. I can also do Definition.findByOwnerType() just fine too, but the query itself is the only thing not working. I'm trying out this grails console as I type this and will get back to you. THanks for the help. :)

Comment: Wait! The reason is opposite to what I was thinking %) **You don't need `mockDomain()` in integration tests**, it is actually harmful - `mockDomain()` only replaces a dynamic GORM methods that GORM already created in integration test environment. That's why it's not working - all the objects are `save()`d to the `List` parameter of `mockDomain()` and never hit the HSQL database. The Criteria is the only method that queries HSQL, which is empty. In short, remove all `mockDomain()`s. Or, better, move the test to unit tests and test it there - it's a better style.

Comment: K, that makes sense, thanks for explaining that. For future reference, would I use just the save() method to put things into the HSQL database for integration testing?

Moving it over to a unit test worked! Thanks again for being very helpful,.. I've been waiting about 2 weeks on the grails user forums...

Comment: Absolutely. In integration tests, nearly the whole application is initialized - except for the presentation layer. So `save()` will work, like everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Grails 2.0.1 now has native @Mock for test criteria, but groupProperty is not implemented yet.

I wrote mock criteria plugin (with groupProperty)

https://github.com/fabiooshiro/plastic-criteria

it works in 1.3.7

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. It is the exact thing I have been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria are supported since grails 2.2. See "Unit Testing GORM" at [What's new in Grails 2.2](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0.RC1/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew22)

Comment: Yes..but some projections are not supported, like groupProperty (as @Sr. Oshiro said)